# Memory usage of algorithm in Scala

Tags: scala, memory

I'm using Scala and I need to monitor memory used by an algorithm executed in my application (a Spark MLlib model). If I use the Java Runtime class (`runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()`) I get the memory used by all the application in the JVM, while I'm interested only in the memory used with the call `model.fit(data)`. I also know VisualVm, but don't understand if there is a programmatically way to get these information by code in my application. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JAMM](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm), which requires running with a Java Agent as well as pulling in the dependency.  Note that the actual runtime size of the objects depends somewhat on the particular Java Virtual Machine on which you're running (and can even vary depending on the VM's options: e.g. depending on whether a 64-bit OpenJDK VM has compressed OOPs, a reference to another object can take 4 or 8 bytes), which is why only a Java Agent can measure the memory usage of an arbitrary object graph.